# Local variable becomes global

Tags: selenium, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

def navigate (URL):
    startTime = time.time()
    browser.get(URL)
    endTime = time.time()
    loadTime = round(endTime - startTime,2)
    return loadTime

def checkHomepage():
    campaigns = []
    rows = len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-top"]/div[4]/div/div/div[6]/div')) #first element is the title bar
    for i in range(2,rows+1):
        for j in range(1,4):
            campaign = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-top"]/div[4]/div/div/div[6]/div['+str(i)+']/div['+str(j)+']/div/div/p/a')
            name = campaign.text
            link = campaign.get_attribute('href')
            campaigns.append([name, link])
    for i in campaigns:
        navigate(i[1])
```

And some other functions

I do:

```
navigate(link)
login(user,pass)
checkHomepage()
```

However, I get AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'time' in checkHomepage
If I print(time) it returns a float.

Why would the time (used only locally in navigate) be stored as global?

Comment: The code you are showing does not assign to `time`, so I don't see how you could get the error you claim. Could you please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that recreates the problem?

Comment: That's all the code i have. Even if i comment out the part of checkKomepage where i build the campaigns list and provide it with another list of link to navigate to, the problem remains. So the code provided is more than minimal. I looked through the debugger: if i use navigate once, i get a global called time that receives a float value. Question is: why? I only use time inside a function and it's not even a variable name.

Comment: I don't have `selenium` installed, but couldn't replicate this with the rest of `navigate`. Also, you don't seem to be doing anything with the `return` value from `navigate`.